# PHP error with mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

I have a simple form which when submitted should count the number of rows in a table which already have the same value as that submitted.

I can't work out why this is returning an error... any ideas?

The error is `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in .../register.php on line 31`

```
$con = mysql_connect("table","user","pass");
if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
mysql_select_db("db", $con);    

function check_input($value, $quoteIt)
  {
      // Stripslashes
      if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
      {
          $value = stripslashes($value);
      }
      // Quote if not a number
      if (is_null($value) || $value=="") {
         $value = 'NULL';
      } else if (!is_numeric($value) && $quoteIt == 1) {
         $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
      }

      return $value;
  }

$useremail = check_input($_POST['useremail'], 1);
// Check to see if email address already exists in USERS table
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $useremail";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo $query;
echo mysql_num_rows($result); //THIS IS LINE 31
mysql_close();
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions. They are being deprecated.

Comment: My guess: $useremail should be in quotes in your SQL statement as it's likely to be a string value

Comment: Thanks @Leigh - what method should I use instead?

Comment: @Mark Baker - the check input function puts the $useremail string into quotes.

Comment: @Tom: Use the mysqli functions or even better use PDO. If it's a new project go for PDO, if not migrating to mysqli will probably cause the least headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see your query error using this, because of query error only this error showing

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks... Really should get into the habit of adding detailed error reports to my code while I'm developing. Noticed a small typo that was causing the problem.

Comment: Please do not use this in production!!! Prefer a function log() that write in a file instead of die(), and read your file...

Comment: Yeah, of course. I'd thought of that. Thanks though - appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("table","user","pass");
if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
mysql_select_db("db", $con);    

function check_input($value, $quoteIt)
  {
      // Stripslashes
      if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
      {
          $value = stripslashes($value);
      }
      // Quote if not a number
      if (is_null($value) || $value=="") {
         $value = 'NULL';
      } else if (!is_numeric($value) && $quoteIt == 1) {
         $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
      }

      return $value;
  }

$useremail = check_input($_POST['useremail'], 1);
// Check to see if email address already exists in USERS table
$query="SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE email = $useremail";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$whatYouWant = $array[0][0];
mysql_close();
?>
```

But Leigh is right, prefer PDO instead of mysql_* functions...

Answer (score -1):

Usually this means the query is wrong. Try backquotes for fields:

```
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$useremail'"
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace

`$result = mysql_query($query);`

with

`$result = mysql_query($query, $con);`